# Evaluation of sequence of characters using getchar() and putchar()

Tags: c, while-loop

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while((c = getchar()) == ' ')
                ;
            putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The above program strips down several consecutive spaces to a single space in a text stream.

I would really appreciate answers to the following questions -

1) If the input is (space space a), does the **1st** `while` test the condition one character at a time?

2)If the **1st** `while` evaluates to true, does the **2nd** `while` condition test using the same character (i.e *1st space*) or the *2nd space*?

Comment: This is going to try to `putchar(EOF)`. AFAIK, that is UB.

Answer (score 1):

> The above program strips down several consecutive spaces to a single
>   space in a text stream.

No it doesnt, this does:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int c;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == ' ') {
            while ((c = getchar()) == ' ');
            if (c == EOF) {
                break;
            }

            putchar(' ');
        }
        putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Modification:**

- Get printing of `(' ')` out of the while loop.

> 1) If the input is (space space a), does the 1st while test the
>   condition one character at a time?

Yes, it will take character, test it in condition, pass it to body if condition is `true` or skip him if `false`. Then it will pick next character till `c == EOF`.

> 2)If the 1st while evaluates to true, does the 2nd while condition
>   test using the same character (i.e 1st space) or the 2nd space?

No, it will read another character (behind that space) and test it again.

Comment: sorry! fixed it.

Comment: Np, i tried to explain your Q's, hope you understand, if not ask me whatever you want.

Comment: @George: What is your expected output if input is (space space a).

Comment: `((c = getchar()) == ' ' && c != EOF)` is unnecessary `' ' != EOF`

Answer (score 0):

The first while keeps on reading a char until it is an EOF (ctrl + D).
The first while will always evaluates to true until you hit EOF.

The second while condition keeps on checking if the input char is a space or not.